# Is there a proper filter for Django Rest Framework to work with PostgreSQL InetAddressField

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF and PostgreSQL to store IP, Subnet and IP Range data.
For the filters I wanted to create a filter that resolves the given reach string and checks if a given IP is not only an exact match, but also part of a subnet or IP range in the database.
PostgreSQL does have a number of operators that can be used for a lookup in InetAddressFields.
[PostgreSQL Documenation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-net.html)

But it seems none are supported by Django/DRF. The django.contrib.postgres.fields package seems to have none of the network address fields.

Is there a well supported module or any other way to implement proper filters for InetAddressField  in DRF?

Comment: This is niche, you'll probably have to do some work writing a drf field.  I laboriously typed "django postgres inetaddress" into google and came up with this: https://pypi.org/project/django-netfields/.   You could use that as the base for a further work.

Comment: I did find that package as well, but was not sure if it is still maintained well. Last update was 10 months ago. I guess I will try to come up with my own implementation   as described in the post linked by Andrew.

Comment: There isn't much "there" in these fields, but they _are_ confusing.  I have mine hanging around still, hstore and arrays.  I would say give it a shot, start writing your own and just refer to that source.  You'll probably find you only need to implement 5% of it, since you don't do everything that is technically possible.